# Running MapReduce word count on Hadoop gives Exception message: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

this is my first Stack Overflow question ever. I've setup my hadoop (2.9.2) single node cluster in pseudo distributed mode. When i try to run hadoop jar C:/MapReduceClient.jar wordcount /input_dir /output_dir, i get the following log with error

```
19/01/16 20:19:17 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
19/01/16 20:19:18 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
19/01/16 20:19:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
19/01/16 20:19:19 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
19/01/16 20:19:19 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1547662294790_0002
19/01/16 20:19:19 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1547662294790_0002
19/01/16 20:19:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://DESKTOP-XXXXXX:8088/proxy/application_1547662294790_0002/
19/01/16 20:19:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1547662294790_0002
19/01/16 20:19:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1547662294790_0002
19/01/16 20:19:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1547662294790_0002 running in uber mode : false
**19/01/16 20:19:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%**
**19/01/16 20:19:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1547662294790_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1547662294790_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1547662294790_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1**
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2019-01-16 20:19:25.234]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1547662294790_0002_02_000001
Exit code: 1
**Exception message: The system cannot find the path specified.**
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.


[2019-01-16 20:19:25.236]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
[2019-01-16 20:19:25.236]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://DESKTOP-XXXXX:8088/cluster/app/application_1547662294790_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt
. Failing the application.
19/01/16 20:19:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

The same setup with the same .jar is working on my other pc and the output is correct. Windows 10 Pro x64 (both)
Only difference is that the working one has java 1.8.0_171 installed

JAVA_HOME= C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
HADOOP_HOME= C:\hadoop-2.9.2

PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\hadoop-2.9.2\bin

My config files:
/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>C:\hadoop-2.9.2\data\namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>C:\hadoop-2.9.2\data\datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>  
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was the default user name being non latin characters messing the node manager up. Checked with a whoami command only to find out that the default user name was "???????"